# Problem displaying DialogFragment from button in Adapter Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I want to display a DialogFragment from my adapter button. I have created a DialogFragment class inside the adapter itself and I want it to show me the dialog when I press the button, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        at com.example.karate_manager.Adapters.AdapterMarket$1.onClick(AdapterMarket.java:106)
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class AdapterMarket extends ArrayAdapter{
private FragmentManager fm;
    Context context;
    int item_Layaut;
    ArrayList<Karateka> data;
    ApiUtils apiUtils;

  public AdapterMarket(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList objects, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.item_Layaut = resource;
        this.data = objects;
        this.fm = fm;
    }

    public void setData(MarketResponse data) {
        if(data!=null){
            this.data = data.getKaratekas();
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(item_Layaut, parent, false);
        }

        String value = String.valueOf(data.get(position).getValue());
        Button buttonValue = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_button_value_karateka);
        buttonValue.setText(value);

        popupBidKarateka(buttonValue);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void popupBidKarateka(Button buttonValue){
        buttonValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context);
                fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment newFragment = new BidKaratekaDialogFragment();
                newFragment.show(fm, "bid" );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the reference in the Fragment:

```
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapterMarket = new AdapterMarket(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_market_layout, marketResponse.getKaratekas(), fragmentManager);
```

Comment: FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(activity1); , what is activity1?

Comment: Sorry I updated that, I tried several codes, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: you need to understand before you jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
               public void onClick(View view) {
                Application activity1 = (Application) view.getContext(); // bad

                FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context); // context must come from FragmentActivity
```

// I have taken assumption is FragmentActivity is the class from where you are calling adapter.

```
                FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment newFragment = new BidKaratekaDialogFragment();
                newFragment.show(fm, "bid" );
            }
        });
```

A wise man said..

> A context is not always an Activity, even when you're in an Activity.
>   It could be an Application, or a wrapper around another context. It's
>   almost always wrong to cast a Context to an Activity. If you
>   absolutely need one, you should pass in an Activity as a parameter,
>   rather than a Context. Or better yet, pass in the support fragment
>   manager directly rather than the activity, since that's all you need
>   it for.

```
public AdapterMarket(@NonNull Context context, FragmentManager fm, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.fm = fm;
        this.item_Layaut = resource;
        this.data = objects;
    }
```

// say, Afragment is calling adapter.

```
AFragment.class
FM fm = getActivity.getSupportFM/getFM();
AdapterMarket market = new AdapterMarket(someContext, fm, ....)
```

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. How I have to pass the Context in this case? I change the code like this ```FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context); ```. But I have the same error.

Comment: From which class you are calling the adapter, pass the reference of that class,

Comment: From a Fragment, I display the adapter in a ListView. Do you mean that?

Comment: then, init FragmentManager from where you are calling, and pass the reference here.then init dialog and show

Comment: Do you know how I can pass the reference of the FragmentManage from my fragment to the adapter?

Comment: I get an error in the constructor when I write ```this.fm = fm;```

Comment: you need to define FragmentManager in Adapter also, don't you think.

Comment: Yes I updated with your code. You can see this above, but I get the same error.

Comment: remove everything fro your onclick, and paste    DialogFragment newFragment = new BidKaratekaDialogFragment();
                newFragment.show(fm, "bid" );